# WebService - Overview

Tags: java, android, sql-server, web-services

There's a lot of info out there for a newbie like myself when it comes to webservices, I acknowledge that.
However, most of the Google results I've seen tend to be focusing on a specific format or strategy, and all of them different to each other.
As a newbie, I am looking to get more of an overview of the various options open to me, their pros & cons... before I start committing to a specific one.

For example, I have an existing webservice created from a SQL Server source via ASP.net and this by default comes out as a DiffGram. So there are articles that tell me how to parse the diffgram data coming into my Android app, but I still do not know if the diffgram is the best option I should be using in the first place.
Should I, for example be changing my webservice to output JSON ?

Does anyone know of a 101 level tutorial or explanation out there ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DiffGram is just another type of XML format. In order to parse the XML data in Android, simply use the XMLFullParse class. 
FYI: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

However if you just want to create a simple data exchange WebService, Json is definitely a better choice. Json is simple, lightweight, easier-to-parse and surely easier to use.
Example:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(jsonString);
json.put("name", "Michael");
json.put("age", "18");

String name = json.opt("name");
```